# Chef execute fails and the same command manually succeeds

Tags: chef-infra

This has happened to me in two different cases, both having to do with using `pip` to install a module that has system dependencies. I'm having an issue where I can `pip install` a python module in a shell as the root user but when I put the same command in an `execute` block it fails. Here's an example:

`PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl /srv/python/venv/bin/pip install pycurl`

That works, but then this block:

```
execute 'install pycurl' do
  cwd '/srv/python/venv'
  environment(
    PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY: 'openssl'
  )
  command '/srv/python/venv/bin/pip install pycurl'
end
```

gives me the following error about `curl-config`:

```
---- Begin output of /srv/python/venv/bin/pip install pycurl ----
   STDOUT: Collecting pycurl
     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/e4/0dbb8735407189f00b33d84122b9be52c790c7c3b25286826f4e1bdb7bde/pycurl-7.43.0.2.tar.gz (214kB)
       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
       Using curl-config (libcurl 7.29.0)
       Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
        raise ConfigurationError(msg)
       __main__.ConfigurationError: Neither curl-config --libs nor curl-config --static-libs succeeded and produced output
```

I've tried setting the `PYCURL_CURL_CONFIG` variable appropriately, but I get the same result, and at any rate what I'm trying to figure out is why I wouldn't at least get the same error on the command line instead of the pip install succeeding. What would be the difference there?

Comment: Try `environment 'PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY' => 'openssl'`? I'm not sure we deal with symbol keys there.

Comment: Also check if `curl-config` is not on a normal `$PATH`, such that your shell can see if but Chef can't.

Comment: Changing the environment syntax doesn't help. The original syntax works because if it's not present I get a different error about ssl libs not being found. `curl-config` is at `/usr/bin/curl-config` which should be available to chef?

Comment: Seems reasonable, does it work if run without the env vars from a login shell?

Comment: (like does `curl-config` find libs in non-standard places or similar)

Comment: `PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY` is necessary in the shell, but specifying the `curl-config` location is not. Even when adding the `PYCURL_CURL_CONFIG` env variable to the execute block it doesn't seem to matter.